# Sort five numbers inserted through user form and send it through AJAX and retrieve the result as JSON on same page

Tags: ajax, json

I am a beginner to ajax, jQuery and json. I want to sort five numbers and for that I need to insert data through an user form and send it through ajax and retrieve the result as json on the same page. Can you please help me out here?
(UPDATE)
The HTML code is like this:

```
<td><input type="number" name="array[]" />
<td><input type="number" name="array[]" />
<td><input type="number" name="array[]" />
<td><input type="number" name="array[]" />
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" />
```

And PHP in another file sort.php goes like this:

```
    $a=$_POST['array'];
    sort($a);
    $b=count($a);
    for($i=0;$i<$b;$i++)
    {   
        echo "$a[$i] <br>";
    }
```

Comment: Please add source code to your question - what have you tried yourself

Comment: i donot know what to do.. Please guide. Any help would be much appreciable

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var array=[];
function addElement()  //this function take the value from the text box and assign the value to an array 
{
var number=$("#addvalue").val();
array.push(number);
$("#addvalue").val(' ');
$("#addvalue").focus();
}
function Sort()  //this function display the number in desending order
{
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
for(j=i+1;j<array.length;j++) {
if(parseInt(array[j]) > parseInt(array[i])) {
var temp=array[i];
array[i]=array[j];
array[j]=temp;  
}}}
$.each(array,function(index)   //and this function display the number.
{
var span=document.createElement("span");
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[index]));
    var i =document.getElementById("array");
    i.appendChild(span);


var br=document.createElement("br");

i.appendChild(br);
});
$("div#array span:first").css("color","green");
};<script>

<body>
<input type="text" id="addvalue"/>
<br/><input type="button" onclick="addElement()" value="Add Number"/> <input type="button" onclick="Greater()" value="Sort">
<div id="array"></div>
</body>
```